# Je suis sûre que les femmes y arriveraient / arriveront

Tags: temps-grammatical, conditionnel, futur, présent

*Vie secrète* de Danielle Steel :

> -- Parce que, en règle générale, ce sont des hommes qui écrivent les romans à suspense, pas des femmes, répéta-t-il avec conviction.
>
> -- C'est complètement idiot, papa. Je suis **sûre** que les femmes y **arriveraient** très bien.

À mon avis, l'emploi du conditionnel après *sûre* est érroné, il faudrait employer le futur ou le présent, *arriveront* ou *arrivent*. Est-ce que, d'après vous, la traduction est correcte ?

Comment: On peut pas décider si une traduction est correcte sans voir l'original :) Mais je dirais que ça marche -- il s'agit d'un "si elles en écrivaient" implicite (qui ne coïncide peut-être pas avec la pensée du personnage, et dans ce cas le conditionnel donnerait la mauvaise idée).

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, merci, je pense que c'est vrai. Car son père vient de dire _ce sont des hommes qui écrivent les romans à suspense, pas des femmes_. Donc, _si elles en écrivaient_ qui est sous-entendi.

Comment: Oui, pourvu qu'elle est de son opinion :) On peut y entendre soit "Elles ne le font pas en vérité", soit "Elles ne sont pas censées le faire"

Answer (score 1):

Donné le contexte de la première phrase, il est admis que les femmes n'écrivent pas les romans à suspense, et donc on peut formuler toutes sortes d'hypothèses, par exemple qu'elles pourraient aussi s'essayer à cette activité, qu'elles aimeraient être actives dans ce domaine, que l'on pourrait les inciter à s'y intéresser, etc. C'est sur cette base que l'on utilise le conditionnel, c'est à dire que l'on ne peut pas admettre de réalité. Le futur est un temps de l'indicatif, c'est à dire un temps du réel ; même s'il existe une incertitude quant à la réalisation de l'action lorsqu'on utilise le futur, on le fait sur la base d'une certitude, la certitude que l'action va être réelle : « Il fera jour demain. », « Je ne pourrai pas rester endormi pendant quatre jours de suite sans une drogue, je vais me réveiller. », etc.

Si dans cette phrase on utilisait le futur on présupposerait qu'il existe un contexte qui doit résulter en le fait que les femmes commenceront à écrire des romans à suspense dans le proche avenir ou qu'elles viennent de commencer. Si une certaine  modification est faite à la phrase, le futur devient obligatoire, et c'est le conditionnel qui n'a pas de sens.

- — Parce que, en règle générale, ce sont des hommes qui écrivent les romans à suspense, pas des femmes, répéta-t-il avec conviction.
  — C'est complètement idiot, papa, elles viennent en fait de commencer, et je suis sûre qu'elles  y arriveront très bien.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :)